# Is there a way to trigger the dblclik event on code in syntax highlighter on keydown?

Tags: jquery, selection, double-click, syntaxhighlighter

I am using http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/ .
It has a feature where on dblclik on the higlighted text, all of it is selected:
[how it looks when doubleclicking on higlighted text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waywF.png)

I would like to achieve the same effect by triggering dblclick on keydown, is this doable?

I managed to catch the keydown event:

```
$(window).keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 65) {
        console.log("Ctrl+A event captured");
        e.preventDefault();
        /* but I dont know how to proceed */
    }
})
```

I am greatefull for any ideas on this matter.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to extend the syntaxhighlighter library to also use `keydown` to detect `CTRL-A` or that you want to create your own library that replicates the behavior of syntaxhighlighter?

Comment: My bad, actually extending the library would be the best choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to extend SyntaxHighlighter you could fork it on GitHub and modify it.

Sign up for a free GitHub account if you don't have one, then visit the [project page](https://github.com/syntaxhighlighter/syntaxhighlighter), and click the `Fork` button.

You could also just download the .ZIP and modify the source. The file you want is in `src/core.js`

The code that attaches `dblclick` is in [core.js](https://github.com/syntaxhighlighter/syntaxhighlighter/blob/master/src/core.js)

```
  if (params.quickCode)
    dom.attachEvent(dom.findElement(element, '.code'), 'dblclick', dom.quickCodeHandler);
```

In your fork of this project, simply add this:

```
  dom.attachEvent(dom.findElement(element, '.code'), 'keydown',   
    function(e)
    {
      if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 65) {
        console.log("Ctrl+A event captured");
        e.preventDefault();
        dom.quickCodeHandler();
        return false;
    }
  });
```

For reference, the code that does the work is in [dom.js](https://github.com/syntaxhighlighter/syntaxhighlighter/blob/master/src/dom.js)

```
/**
 * Quick code mouse double click handler.
 */
function quickCodeHandler(e)
{
  var target = e.target,
    highlighterDiv = findParentElement(target, '.syntaxhighlighter'),
    container = findParentElement(target, '.container'),
    textarea = document.createElement('textarea'),
    highlighter
    ;

  if (!container || !highlighterDiv || findElement(container, 'textarea'))
    return;

  //highlighter = highlighters.get(highlighterDiv.id);

  // add source class name
  addClass(highlighterDiv, 'source');

  // Have to go over each line and grab it's text, can't just do it on the
  // container because Firefox loses all \n where as Webkit doesn't.
  var lines = container.childNodes,
    code = []
    ;

  for (var i = 0, l = lines.length; i < l; i++)
    code.push(lines[i].innerText || lines[i].textContent);

  // using \r instead of \r or \r\n makes this work equally well on IE, FF and Webkit
  code = code.join('\r');

    // For Webkit browsers, replace nbsp with a breaking space
    code = code.replace(/\u00a0/g, " ");

  // inject <textarea/> tag
  textarea.appendChild(document.createTextNode(code));
  container.appendChild(textarea);

  // preselect all text
  textarea.focus();
  textarea.select();

  // set up handler for lost focus
  attachEvent(textarea, 'blur', function(e)
  {
    textarea.parentNode.removeChild(textarea);
    removeClass(highlighterDiv, 'source');
  });
};
```